# what's matter with my account, it becomes a new one

Tags: support, user-accounts

I have asked 4 questions
today I clicked like create account or something, use google email to login
and my account looks like a new one. and only have 1 question.
how can I get my old account?

Answer (score 1):

You asked [4 questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430839/jacky-zhou), not Super User. [One of those](https://superuser.com/questions/614089/how-to-read-the-file-in-u-disk-copied-from-mac) was migrated here.

There's no 'old account', just accounts on different sites catering to different audiences.

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge your accounts - go [here](https://meta.superuser.com/contact/user-merge). Its under contact us, at the footer, but this is a direct link.

Comment: na, he doesn't have duplicate accounts